# Regex and BeautifulSoup using Python

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have to parse (scrap) a webpage (html) and get some information, store it in a csv.

I have to do this using both Regex and BeautifulSoup, and I have absolute no prior experience with Python.

I'll really appreciate if anyone can guide me accordingly for the code. I have managed to install python and BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Question is : the code. I tried some bs code, but the python idle returned some error , to install parsing library. so I installed html5lib somehow. But I want code to write in regex and bs, so as to parse a html page on web and get the data in csv. like for example any text in 'bold' on this stackoverflow page.

Comment: So you dont't know anything about Python and want us to teach you? That won't work. Start with the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For python 3 :
Read a web page with the following commands:

```
import urllib.request

your_url = "http://stackoverflow.com/"   # for example

opener = urllib.request.FancyURLopener({})
f = opener.open( your_url )
vr = f.read()
vr = vr.decode()
print( vr )
```

And match some regexp, for example, with:

```
import re

re_flags = ( re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE )
m = re.search( r"<div>\s*(\d*)\s*</div>" , vr , re_flags )
if m :
    print( m.groups()[0] )
```

If it find the regexp the matched string is written in  m.groups()[0]

And clearly you must use your personal regexp in re.search

Visit:
http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is beautifulsoup doc how to parse HTML, since you didn't specify it ..

```
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Parsing a Document
```

Regexp, read docs like Giggi suggested, if you don't understand something in particular, don't be afraid to ask, but we would need more specific info, what do you want exactly to parse? what is input HTML and what do you expect as a result?